# jQuery "guid" is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This error keeps coming up in my JavaScript error logging, In IE 7 and 8.  But I can't reproduce it for the life in me!

> "guid" is null or not an object

I'm using jQuery 1.4.1 so it's not the `.hover()` problem that comes up in google searches.

the error is happening here (around line 1570 ):

```
  if (!handler.guid) {
        handler.guid = jQuery.guid++;
  }
```

The page it's happening on is really really complex, dialogs, ajax content, tabs, accordions,  you  name it, it's on there.  and worse, it's internal, so I can't give you guys a link to play with it.

I can't make a fiddle b/c I can't reproduce the problem :(

I know this is a long shot, and I'm more then willing to put up a bounty for this when I am able to.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I should be looking for to solve this? 
I'm also using jquery Ui 1.8.11 and a variety of plugins.

Edit:  Here is the larger part of the jquery code that is throwing the error. it's part of jquery's event  stuff.

```
add: function (elem, types, handler, data) {
            if (elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 8) {
                return;
            }

            // For whatever reason, IE has trouble passing the window object
            // around, causing it to be cloned in the process
            if (elem.setInterval && (elem !== window && !elem.frameElement)) {
                elem = window;
            }

            // Make sure that the function being executed has a unique ID
            if (!handler.guid) {
                handler.guid = jQuery.guid++;
            }

            // if data is passed, bind to handler
            if (data !== undefined) {
                // Create temporary function pointer to original handler
                var fn = handler;

                // Create unique handler function, wrapped around original handler
                handler = jQuery.proxy(fn);

                // Store data in unique handler
                handler.data = data;
            }

            // Init the element's event structure
            var events = jQuery.data(elem, "events") || jQuery.data(elem, "events", {}),
            handle = jQuery.data(elem, "handle"), eventHandle;

            if (!handle) {
                eventHandle = function () {
                    // Handle the second event of a trigger and when
                    // an event is called after a page has unloaded
                    return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && !jQuery.event.triggered ?
                    jQuery.event.handle.apply(eventHandle.elem, arguments) :
                    undefined;
                };

                handle = jQuery.data(elem, "handle", eventHandle);
            }

            // If no handle is found then we must be trying to bind to one of the
            // banned noData elements
            if (!handle) {
                return;
            }

            // Add elem as a property of the handle function
            // This is to prevent a memory leak with non-native
            // event in IE.
            handle.elem = elem;

            // Handle multiple events separated by a space
            // jQuery(...).bind("mouseover mouseout", fn);
            types = types.split(/\s+/);

            var type, i = 0;

            while ((type = types[i++])) {
                // Namespaced event handlers
                var namespaces = type.split(".");
                type = namespaces.shift();

                if (i > 1) {
                    handler = jQuery.proxy(handler);

                    if (data !== undefined) {
                        handler.data = data;
                    }
                }

                handler.type = namespaces.slice(0).sort().join(".");

                // Get the current list of functions bound to this event
                var handlers = events[type],
                special = this.special[type] || {};

                // Init the event handler queue
                if (!handlers) {
                    handlers = events[type] = {};

                    // Check for a special event handler
                    // Only use addEventListener/attachEvent if the special
                    // events handler returns false
                    if (!special.setup || special.setup.call(elem, data, namespaces, handler) === false) {
                        // Bind the global event handler to the element
                        if (elem.addEventListener) {
                            elem.addEventListener(type, handle, false);
                        } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
                            elem.attachEvent("on" + type, handle);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (special.add) {
                    var modifiedHandler = special.add.call(elem, handler, data, namespaces, handlers);
                    if (modifiedHandler && jQuery.isFunction(modifiedHandler)) {
                        modifiedHandler.guid = modifiedHandler.guid || handler.guid;
                        modifiedHandler.data = modifiedHandler.data || handler.data;
                        modifiedHandler.type = modifiedHandler.type || handler.type;
                        handler = modifiedHandler;
                    }
                }

                // Add the function to the element's handler list
                handlers[handler.guid] = handler;

                // Keep track of which events have been used, for global triggering
                this.global[type] = true;
            }

            // Nullify elem to prevent memory leaks in IE
            elem = null;
        }
```

EDIT:
I spent about 25 minutes trying to produce this error with no luck.  I was opening and closing tabs(ajax loaded), trying to get them to change before the loaded and whatnot.  also opening and closing dialogs (ajax loaded) and doing things that added and removed content ajaxly.  nothing would break!

Not sure if this is helpful, but here is a user agent string that is causing the error:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; GTB7.0; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

and here is another:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; MS-RTC LM 8)

errorception (our javascript error logging service)  doesn't seem to keep individual user agents, so i only have the two.

EDIT: 
I think i've narrowed it down to our quick search. which uses jquery ui Auto Complete,  and jquery.jail (async image loading).
I have tweaked jquery ui auto complete a bit. and am using the HTML extension.

Here is the code:

```
    /*
     * jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.11
     *
     * Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
     * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
     * http://jquery.org/license
     *
     * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete
     *
     * Depends:
     *  jquery.ui.core.js
     *  jquery.ui.widget.js
     *  jquery.ui.position.js

 */

(function( $, undefined ) {

// used to prevent race conditions with remote data sources
var requestIndex = 0;

$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {
    options: {
        appendTo: "body",
        autoFocus: false,
        delay: 300,
        minLength: 1,
        position: {
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            collision: "none"
        },
        source: null
    },

    pending: 0,

    _create: function() {
        var self = this,
            doc = this.element[ 0 ].ownerDocument,
            suppressKeyPress;

        this.element
            .addClass( "ui-autocomplete-input" )
            .attr( "autocomplete", "off" )
            // TODO verify these actually work as intended
            .attr({
                role: "textbox",
                "aria-autocomplete": "list",
                "aria-haspopup": "true"
            })
            .bind( "keydown.autocomplete", function( event ) {
                if ( self.options.disabled || self.element.attr( "readonly" ) ) {
                    return;
                }

                suppressKeyPress = false;
                var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
                switch( event.keyCode ) {
                case keyCode.PAGE_UP:
                    self._move( "previousPage", event );
                    break;
                case keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
                    self._move( "nextPage", event );
                    break;
                case keyCode.UP:
                    self._move( "previous", event );
                    // prevent moving cursor to beginning of text field in some browsers
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case keyCode.DOWN:
                    self._move( "next", event );
                    // prevent moving cursor to end of text field in some browsers
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case keyCode.ENTER:
                case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                    // when menu is open and has focus
                    if ( self.menu.active ) {
                        // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
                        // which causes forms to submit
                        suppressKeyPress = true;
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    //passthrough - ENTER and TAB both select the current element
                case keyCode.TAB:
                    if ( !self.menu.active ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    self.menu.select( event );
                    break;
                case keyCode.ESCAPE:

                    //This is changed by ME!   added self.term = ''; and also self.element.blur();  //this was so that when you hit esc, it clears the box, and puts it back to an empty state.

                    self.term = '';
                    self.element.val( self.term );
                    self.close( event );
                    self.element.blur();
                    break;
                default:
                    // keypress is triggered before the input value is changed
                    clearTimeout( self.searching );
                    self.searching = setTimeout(function() {
                        // only search if the value has changed
                        if ( self.term != self.element.val() ) {
                            self.selectedItem = null;
                            self.search( null, event );
                        }
                    }, self.options.delay );
                    break;
                }
            })
            .bind( "keypress.autocomplete", function( event ) {
                if ( suppressKeyPress ) {
                    suppressKeyPress = false;
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .bind( "focus.autocomplete", function() {
                if ( self.options.disabled ) {
                    return;
                }

                self.selectedItem = null;
                self.previous = self.element.val();
            })
            .bind( "blur.autocomplete", function( event ) {
                if ( self.options.disabled ) {
                    return;
                }

                clearTimeout( self.searching );
                // clicks on the menu (or a button to trigger a search) will cause a blur event
                self.closing = setTimeout(function() {
                    self.close( event );
                    self._change( event );
                }, 150 );
            });
        this._initSource();
        this.response = function() {
            return self._response.apply( self, arguments );
        };
        this.menu = $( "<ul></ul>" )
            .addClass( "ui-autocomplete" )
            .appendTo( $( this.options.appendTo || "body", doc )[0] )
            // prevent the close-on-blur in case of a "slow" click on the menu (long mousedown)
            .mousedown(function( event ) {
                // clicking on the scrollbar causes focus to shift to the body
                // but we can't detect a mouseup or a click immediately afterward
                // so we have to track the next mousedown and close the menu if
                // the user clicks somewhere outside of the autocomplete
                var menuElement = self.menu.element[ 0 ];
                if ( !$( event.target ).closest( ".ui-menu-item" ).length ) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $( document ).one( 'mousedown', function( event ) {
                            if ( event.target !== self.element[ 0 ] &&
                                event.target !== menuElement &&
                                !$.ui.contains( menuElement, event.target ) ) {
                                self.close();
                            }
                        });
                    }, 1 );
                }

                // use another timeout to make sure the blur-event-handler on the input was already triggered
                setTimeout(function() {
                    clearTimeout( self.closing );
                }, 13);
            })
            .menu({
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    var item = ui.item.data( "item.autocomplete" );
                    if ( false !== self._trigger( "focus", event, { item: item } ) ) {
                        // use value to match what will end up in the input, if it was a key event
                        if ( /^key/.test(event.originalEvent.type) ) {
                            //self.element.val( item.value );       //changed by me, if they use the keys, don't change the text! don't want a textbox with a number in it.

                        }
                    }
                },
                selected: function( event, ui ) {
                    var item = ui.item.data( "item.autocomplete" ),
                        previous = self.previous;

                    // only trigger when focus was lost (click on menu)
                    if ( self.element[0] !== doc.activeElement ) {
                        self.element.focus();
                        self.previous = previous;
                        // #6109 - IE triggers two focus events and the second
                        // is asynchronous, so we need to reset the previous
                        // term synchronously and asynchronously :-(
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            self.previous = previous;
                            self.selectedItem = item;
                        }, 1);
                    }

                    if ( false !== self._trigger( "select", event, { item: item } ) ) {
                        self.element.val( item.value );
                    }
                    // reset the term after the select event
                    // this allows custom select handling to work properly
                    self.term = self.element.val();

                    self.close( event );
                    self.selectedItem = item;
                },
                blur: function( event, ui ) {
                    // don't set the value of the text field if it's already correct
                    // this prevents moving the cursor unnecessarily
                    if ( self.menu.element.is(":visible") &&
                        ( self.element.val() !== self.term ) ) {
                        self.element.val( self.term );
                    }
                }
            })
            .zIndex( this.element.zIndex() + 1 )
            // workaround for jQuery bug #5781 http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5781
            .css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
            .hide()
            .data( "menu" );
        if ( $.fn.bgiframe ) {
             this.menu.element.bgiframe();
        }
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.element
            .removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-input" )
            .removeAttr( "autocomplete" )
            .removeAttr( "role" )
            .removeAttr( "aria-autocomplete" )
            .removeAttr( "aria-haspopup" );
        this.menu.element.remove();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
    },

    _setOption: function( key, value ) {
        $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply( this, arguments );
        if ( key === "source" ) {
            this._initSource();
        }
        if ( key === "appendTo" ) {
            this.menu.element.appendTo( $( value || "body", this.element[0].ownerDocument )[0] )
        }
        if ( key === "disabled" && value && this.xhr ) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    },

    _initSource: function() {
        var self = this,
            array,
            url;
        if ( $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
            array = this.options.source;
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term) );
            };
        } else if ( typeof this.options.source === "string" ) {
            url = this.options.source;
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                if ( self.xhr ) {
                    //added try catch
                    try{
                        if(self.xhr.abort != null){ 
                            self.xhr.abort();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(err){

                    }

                    delete self.xhr;

                }

                self.xhr = $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: request,
                    dataType: "json",
                    autocompleteRequest: ++requestIndex,
                    success: function( data, status ) {
                        if ( this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex ) {
                            response( data );
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        if ( this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex ) {
                            response( [] );
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        } else {
            this.source = this.options.source;
        }
    },

    search: function( value, event ) {
        value = value != null ? value : this.element.val();

        // always save the actual value, not the one passed as an argument
        this.term = this.element.val();

        if ( value.length < this.options.minLength ) {
            return this.close( event );
        }

        clearTimeout( this.closing );
        if ( this._trigger( "search", event ) === false ) {
            return;
        }

        return this._search( value );
    },

    _search: function( value ) {
        this.pending++;
        this.element.addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );

        this.source( { term: value }, this.response );
    },

    _response: function( content ) {
        if ( !this.options.disabled && content && content.length ) {
            content = this._normalize( content );
            this._suggest( content );
            this._trigger( "open" );
        } else {
            this.close();
        }
        this.pending--;
        if ( !this.pending ) {
            this.element.removeClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );
        }
    },

    close: function( event ) {
        clearTimeout( this.closing );
        if ( this.menu.element.is(":visible") ) {
            this.menu.element.hide();
            this.menu.deactivate();
            this._trigger( "close", event );
        }
    },

    _change: function( event ) {
        if ( this.previous !== this.element.val() ) {
            this._trigger( "change", event, { item: this.selectedItem } );
        }
    },

    _normalize: function( items ) {
        // assume all items have the right format when the first item is complete
        if ( items.length && items[0].label && items[0].value ) {
            return items;
        }
        return $.map( items, function(item) {
            if ( typeof item === "string" ) {
                return {
                    label: item,
                    value: item
                };
            }
            return $.extend({
                label: item.label || item.value,
                value: item.value || item.label
            }, item );
        });
    },

    _suggest: function( items ) {
        var ul = this.menu.element
            .empty()
            .zIndex( this.element.zIndex() + 1 );
        this._renderMenu( ul, items );
        // TODO refresh should check if the active item is still in the dom, removing the need for a manual deactivate
        this.menu.deactivate();
        this.menu.refresh();

        // size and position menu
        ul.show();
        this._resizeMenu();
        ul.position( $.extend({
            of: this.element
        }, this.options.position ));

        if ( this.options.autoFocus ) {
            this.menu.next( new $.Event("mouseover") );
        }
    },

    _resizeMenu: function() {
        var ul = this.menu.element;
        ul.outerWidth( Math.max(
            ul.width( "" ).outerWidth(),
            this.element.outerWidth()
        ) );
    },

    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this;
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    },

    _renderItem: function( ul, item) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( $( "<a></a>" ).text( item.label ) )
            .appendTo( ul );
    },

    _move: function( direction, event ) {
        if ( !this.menu.element.is(":visible") ) {
            this.search( null, event );
            return;
        }
        if ( this.menu.first() && /^previous/.test(direction) ||
                this.menu.last() && /^next/.test(direction) ) {
            this.element.val( this.term );
            this.menu.deactivate();
            return;
        }
        this.menu[ direction ]( event );
    },

    widget: function() {
        return this.menu.element;
    }
    });

    $.extend( $.ui.autocomplete, {
        escapeRegex: function( value ) {
            return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
        },
        filter: function(array, term) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i" );
            return $.grep( array, function(value) {
                return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
            });
        }
    });

    }( jQuery ));
```

the html extension:
https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/e34c9457619a13a01774f7954175320ac1e283c1/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js

and here is where you can find JAIL:
https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL

I tried breaking it by typing fast, using the mouse and arrows, clicking around, hitting esc, hiting ctrl, tab, all sorts of things. still doesn't break.

Edit: I've added a 250 rep bounty!   There has to be someone out there who has come across this.

EDIT:

I've just seen a slightly different version of this error, now from IE 9! 
Unable to get value of the property "guid": object is null or undefined
exact same line as the "guid" is null or not an object.

so, either handler is null, or jQuery is null.  i'm going to go with handler, since if jQuery was null, i'd have a lot of other problems.

so this means, i'm trying to attach a guid, to a handler that doesn't exist.  how could that even be possible?

Edit:

Here is the code that is setting up the auto complete widget:

```
<div class="watermarkText" >
    <label for="UserLookUp" class="over" id="UserLookUpLable"  ><%= Web.QuickSearchGhostText.HtmlEncode%></label>
    <input type="text" id="UserLookUp" name="UserLookUp" style="width:250px;vertical-align:middle;" />
</div>

<img src="ClearLookUp.jpg" alt="Clear Text" id="ClearLookUp"  />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#UserLookUp").autocomplete({
            source: 'aurl',
            minLength: 2,
            delay: 2,
            autoFocus: true,
            html: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                window.location = "a url".replace("0", ui.item.value);
                return false;
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {

                $('img.LookUpControlPicture').jail();
            }
        });

        $('#UserLookUpLable').labelOver('over');

        $('#ClearLookUp').click(function () {
            $('#UserLookUp').val('');
            $('#UserLookUp').autocomplete("search");
            $('#UserLookUp').blur();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Maybe it's coming from the labelOver plugin (which i have changed, a lot).

Here's the code for it:

```
jQuery.fn.labelOver = function (overClass) {
    ///<summary> 
    ///    applied to the label(s) to be ghosted over a textbox.  
    //     generally used like so: $('.watermarkText').find('label').labelOver('over'); 
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="overClass" type="string">the class to apply to the label to style it as ghosted text.</param>
    ///<returns>nothing</returns>

    return this.each(function () {
        var label = jQuery(this);
        var f = label.attr('for');
        if (f) {
            var input = jQuery('#' + f);

            this.hide = function () {
                // label.css({ textIndent: -10000 })
                label.css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }

            this.show = function () {
                if (input.val() == '') label.css('visibility', 'visible');     //{ textIndent: 0 }
            }

            // handlers
            input.focus(this.hide);
            input.blur(this.show);

            //added by me
            input.change(function () {
                if (input.val() == '') {
                    label.css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
                else {
                    label.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
            });
            label.addClass(overClass).click(function () { input.focus() });

            if (input.val() != '') this.hide();
        }
    })
}
```

I don't see anything really obvious, but maybe i'm missing something.

Here is what i've come up with to log the error:

```
try {
    if (!handler.guid) {
          handler.guid = jQuery.guid++;
    }
}
catch (err) {
                var message = "handler.guid = jQuery.guid++ Error! \n";
                message += 'types: ' + types + '\n';
                if (typeof data != 'undefined') {
                    if (typeof data == 'object') {

                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            message += i + ' : ' + v + '\n';
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        message += 'elem id:' + $(elem).attr('id') + 'elem class: ' + $(elem).attr('class');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    message += 'data is undefined';
                }

                var url = window.location.href;
                var linenumber = 1579;
                v2LogTheErrorToElmah(message, url, linenumber, 0);

   }
```

Comment: I don't understand. You said you can't reproduce the problem. What is the problem then? when does it occurs?

Comment: my error logging is showing it coming up for our end users. 100's of times.

Comment: What is the error? What's the value of `handler`?

Comment: the error is : `"guid" is null or not an object.`  I don't know what's in handler.  all i have is the error message and a line number, which points to the included code.  I know it's not much to go on.

Comment: @Florent This is jquery's event add: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L35

Comment: add a bit of code to take handler and error etc and post to a server, that server creates an email and you have client side error control, but why not use something else like a date of now   or ticks or your own guid generation code

Comment: @davethecoder   this code is deep in the bowels of jQuery, not really something i want to mess around with.

Comment: That means that `jQuery.guid` is not defined... Are you sure you are using jQuery 1.4.1? Before that, the `guid` variable was not defined.

Comment: @Florent  yes, i'm certain it.s 1.4.1  I think it wouldn't be an intermitent problem if it wasn't.

Comment: HI  i did not mean change jquery  i meant change jQuery.guid++;   with your own thats not jquery, or is the whole code jquery code, bit confusing because you only added a couple of lines of code of were the problem is, but not how you get to the problem, so just throwing ideas.

Comment: do you know what guid, you have  handler.guid and jquery.guid, is it jquery or handler thats failing ????

Comment: I'll add a bit more context for the code.  It's jQuerys's code that is throwing the error, i wish i had a stack trace, it'd be so much easier to track down!

Comment: you can step through the code with developer tools in IE i think, press f12 and swap to IE7 and then put break point on javascript and run

Comment: do you have any idea what part of your code is causing an error in this section, I.E  on a tab change or when a button is clicked or an ajax call or something?    i would look were ever you are ADDING content to your page, i.e table results or something, maybe you have a value that comming out null from json maybe

Comment: i have no idea where it's coming from, nothing simple like a tab change, or i'd be able to reproduce it.  I'll start looking more closely at adding/ removing content.

Comment: My guess is that you're calling the jQuery method incorrectly by passing invalid arguments (e.g. `handler` may not be a function). Try reproducing the problem in a browser like Google Chrome or Firefox (with Firebug). You should be able to get a stack trace when the error occurs and locate the part of your code that is calling that method.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens  the error has never occured in any other browser then IE 7 and 8!  I think you may be on to something with calling a jquery method in correctly though.  that is the one thing that googling the problem came up with, calling `.hover` with only 1 function in jquery 1.3.2.

Comment: Is it possible that this issue comes up depending on the users interaction on the page? I.E some other part of your code includes an older version of jQuery based on the selection of a radio button or something?

Comment: @Shawn an excellent idea, but I only have jquery 1.4.1 in my scripts. I do believe it is some interaction that is causing the error, but i can pin down what the interaction is.

Comment: I've added another error message, and a bit more information.

Comment: I'm away for the weekend, so don't panic if i don't reply to any questions. I am NOT abandoning this quest!

Comment: Can you upgrade jQuery? And what do you get if you put the following after `if (!handler.guid) {`: `alert(typeof handler.guid);var tempstring='';for(temp in handler){tempstring+=temp+"\n";}alert(tempstring);tempstring=null;temp=null;`?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff   i can't upgrade jquery, there are to many breaking changes in behaviours.   Because I can't reproduce this error myself, adding alerts into the code isn't really an option either :(  thanks though

Comment: But can't you download [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) and [an IE Virtual Machine from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=11575)? Then you would be able to test it in IE 7-8.

Comment: Are you using a custom version of jQuery? If so can you try to re-download the original version and see if the error still occurs?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff can a virtual machine access local host? i've never been able to get that to work.   Doesn't change the fact that I can't get the error to happen!

Comment: @tftd :  It's got a few hacks and bug fixes in it.  I don't think it's an actual problem with jquery, i think it's something in my implementation.

Comment: Hey Everyone,  Thanks for all the ideas.  I'm going to push this error logging to the live site next week when i get back from vacation (i wanted to get it in before, but ran out of time).   Hopefully that will give us some more to go on.   in the mean time,  the bounty will go to @machineghost  for pointing me in the direction of how to go about getting more information about the error.    I may add another bounty once i have more information, if I still can't figure it out!

Comment: Virtual machines *can* access `localhost`, though not by going to `localhost`. You have to find the local network IP address of the host, it will be `192.168.1.xx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a year since I asked this, and I had given up.  Then, I had to ajaxly load some pictures for a new feature and BAM  I saw this happen in my development environment!

It was caused by the [jQuery.Jail plugin](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL), as I suspected but could never prove.  I have an older version (0.9.5).  When I upgraded to 1.0  The error went away.  Strangely, the plugin behaves fine, even when the error occurs.

I have no idea what exactly in the plugin was causing it.  It was `handler` that was actually null, not `GUID`,  so this will take care of a LOT of the errors I have in my log!

Just a note to other people, for the future, If you are using this old version, you probably are also using an old version of jQuery, so when you switch to the 1.0 version, it uses `.on` instead of `.bind`.  so make sure you have a version of jQuery that supports that, or just edit the plugin and change all the `.on` to `.bind`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems very likely that the problem is an incorrect event handler, since:

```
$('body').click(1);
```

reproduces that exact error in IE.  However, without seeing all of your code, there's no way to find the specific error.

What I'd recommend trying instead is that you modify the jQuery code (temporarily) to add the following line:

```
if (typeof handler != 'function') {alert(handler); alert(type); alert(data); alert(this);}
```

(and maybe add some more alerts if those aren't enough).

That should go inside `jQuery.each(["bind", "one"], function( i, name ) {`, after all the argument parsing but just before the line `var handler = name === "one" ? jQuery.proxy( fn, function( event ) {`.  This is line 2324 for me, but it might be different for you.

Once you've added that line you should be able to use your site, and when you make the bad event hookup (before the error ever occurs) you should get a barrage of alerts that (hopefully) tell you what's going wrong.

Or, worst case scenario, if you try this and can't find any bad event hookups, at least you'll be able to rule that out as a possible cause of the problem.

Comment: i can't fill my production code with alerts!!!  you could be on to something with the event handler though.

Comment: You of course can also use console.log or, even better, your error-to-server-reporting mechanism.

Comment: Ie 7/ 8 doesn't have a console and i don't have control over the error reporting. it's http://errorception.com/  i supose i could write my own little handler that posts to some service... hmmm

Comment: If you don't want to fill your production code with alerts, another option is to use AJAX calls to track this information.  You could easily roll your own on the server-side or, if you're using Google Analytics already, you could use custom analytics events to do the tracking (it's basically just `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','foo', 'bar'])`)

Comment: I can't impliment this until i get back from vacation late next week.  I will award you the bounty(before it end), since you gave me the idea of how i could get more information about the error.  Once I get the extra error logging in place,  I'll hopefully be able to track down the actual problem, and post it as the answer.

Comment: Good luck; I hope the error tracking helps reveal the core issue.

Answer (score 3):

Quick possibility and something I check for when I get odd errors like this is to make sure jQuery isn't being included multiple times.

If you try what machineghost suggested (modifying jQuery source) and you find that it's not logging, or it stops logging at a certain point that'll be a giveaway. Or just look at your http requests in Firebug/Chrome's network profiler ;)

---

Some rationale: sometimes these things will end up pulling in dependencies. For example, if you append a fragment of markup that contains a `<script src="some_other_jquery"></script>`.

It's odd for a global property on the jQuery object to be set to null or otherwise removed.

The next time you reproduce the error you'll want to inspect the jQuery object a bit. Check jQuery.guid (should be null, but just confirm for yourself). jQuery.fn.jquery will give you the version number of your jQuery library.

---

Just browsed the comments and saw that you've checked for this.

Comment: thanks for the idea koobz,  there is no way for jQuery to be included more then once, but that was a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

How about just patching your version of jQuery:

```
if (!handler.guid) {
  handler.guid = jQuery.guid = (jQuery.guid||0) + 1;
}
```

The code is equivalent, but yet more compatible with IE7. I recommend trying to reproduce the problem first, if you can. But this should prevent it from happening in the future.

Comment: this would fix it if it's jQUery.guid that is null, but not if it's handler.guid (or handler).  which i am leaning towards being the case.  could be worth trying though, to at least solve which it is that is causing the error.

Comment: Ultimately, you're going to have to try your best to reproduce the bug. Until then, you're not going to have the confidence that it is fixed.

Comment: yea, i know that,  I've spent probably 10-15 hours trying to reproduce it!!  If the errors stop showing up in my log for a week or so, i can be pretty confident it's solved, since it occurs several times a day currently.

Comment: For my webapp, I set up a silent JavaScript error reporting system (as another commenter has suggested). I had it email me the JavaScript stack trace for the logs. If you are interested, I can post that as a separate answer.

Comment: i've written somethign like that before, it posted to an mvc action which then logged it to elmah.  i'm going to try rigging that up.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

- Of course the fact that both are XP running IE7 and have .NET libraries going way back suggests to me that they aren't exactly cooking with gas. I would attempt to duplicate with XP and IE7 but also look into tools that slow down the speed of processing on your test machines. At slow enough speeds in IE before 9, you might be running into some kind of a timing issue where something that shouldn't have been assumed to be ready or loaded or available usually is on modern browsers but is failing to be ready on older browsers on like a pentium or 386 or TRS-80 or something. The speed differences between IE7 and today's browsers (even IE9 which is still the slowest of the modern lot) are staggering. Failing that, drastically reduce RAM to whatever it was we were using back in the days when IE7 on XP was new. With all that UI flying around on one page, that might just be too much for an old pre-Vista machine.
- Oops. NM. I had previously written here that it was Windows NT in the U-A string but NT 5.1 is really XP. Still, attempting to duplicate errors with a similar setup to match that U-A might be helpful. Also, I believe a lot of MS's built-in browsers for other apps was just IE7 cobbled together and crammed into a pane so it's possible that's not actually be the IE7 browser. I don't know what to make of all those .NET versions. I don't spend a lot of time analyzing U-A strings but that seems like a lot.

Added questions:

- I feel dumb for not asking earlier, but do you have any of this code firing before document.ready? The non-crap browsers render HTML/CSS and execute JS much faster than IE so HTML that's not ready in IE at a certain point might be ready in Firefox and Chrome.
- What is the point of that source:null option at the top of the ui.autocomplete code. I don't see options.source getting set anywhere.
- Have you verified that HTML surrounding the stuff that you suspect is causing the problem isn't broken? Older IE doesn't handle HTML breakage as well as Chrome and Firefox do.
- Have you ever seen this error happen? I'm assuming something reports to your back end that the error is happening based on what you've said.

I would look to the elem var to try and nail down exact context with the following modification to the jquery code:

```
try{
  if (!handler.guid) {
        handler.guid = jQuery.guid++;
  }
} catch(e){
    var alertMsg = [];
    alertMsg.push('GUID FAIL');
    if(elem.id) { alertMsg.push('ID: ' + elem.id); }
    if(elem.className) { alertMsg.push('CLASS: ' + elem.id); }
    if(!elem.id && !elem.className){
        alertMsg.push('CONSTRUCTOR: ' + elem.constructor.toString().match(/^[^(]*/));
    }
    alert(alertMsg.join('\n'));
}
```

If this helps you sort out the exact source of the problem, I would then check the args you're passing into the JQ method that's the source.

Comment: all my javascript is wrapped in $(function(){};,  i'm not sure what source: null is for, it's part of the plugin and i haven't changed that part at all.  the HTML looks ok, and I haven't seen this error with my own eyes, just seen it in my errorception logs.